# Send signal to av receiver with android

Tags: java, android, sockets, telnet

i want to implement a function in my android app to turn on/off my av receiver.
Therefore i created a socket and send a command via Telnet to the receiver, but nothing happens.
The Socket is created successfully!

My av receiver is a Denon x-2000 and according to the official protocol I have to send a PWSTANDBY command.

```
 public void turnOff(View v){
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket s = null;
            PrintWriter out = null;
            BufferedReader in= null;
            try{
                InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.100.228");
                s= new Socket(ia, 23);
                out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            } catch(IOException e){

            }
            Log.v("output","send standby");
            out.println("PWSTANDBY");
            out.flush();

            try {
                if(in.ready())
                Log.v("input", in.readLine());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            out.close();
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution by myself, I changed the line

```
out.println("PWSTANDBY");
```

to

```
out.print("PWSTANDBY\r");
```

and it works.